# Batch files - Create files based off a list

Tags: php, batch-file, command-line, fsutil

I am looking to create a large number of rather small php files based off a pre-defined list. I would also like to insert something into these .php files. I have the list ready and there are just slightly over 7500 files to create. Each line is a different `PHP` file, such as

```
Cheese.php
Cheeese.php
Cheeeese.php
```

You get the idea, they change slightly. The list is already in a text file and I need to read the text file line-by-line and create a file using that line. I already know the command to create files through command line is `fsutil file createnew` I am just looking for a way to make it do this by using the massive text file and then also add the same pre-defined text into each of the `PHP` files that I am creating.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I would do this manually but 7500 is a bit time consuming!

Comment: Why on earth do you need 7500 php files? Perhaps you should look for a url router script

Comment: Is it a command line or a php question ?

Comment: just a crazy idea, one php file, and one rewrite, rule can handle every request to a server.

Comment: My reasons are a little outlandish, safe to say it's more of an experiment. This is a command line question as per the title, it's just for creating `php` files. Unfortunately, a single php file in this instance won't do. I know what you mean as I tend to keep almost everything centered around a single file and branch off from it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in a batch-file is fairly simple:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (phplist.txt) do (
Echo. >> "C:\Path\To\MainDirectory\%%~a"
)
```

The above will create all the listed files blank.

You can modify this by replacing the middle line with whatever you want and refering to the file names as `%%~a`.